# Ruby split concatenated array element into separate array row and export to CSV

Tags: arrays, ruby, csv, split

I am trying to split a concatenated field from a CSV and add it to a new row in Ruby.  Here is an example of the data and desired output.

Sample Data

```
Year    Make    Model
1999    Chevy   Camaro; Corvette; Cruz
2001    Ford    Mustang; Shelby; SHO
```

Desired Output

```
Year    Make    Model
1999    Chevy   Camaro
1999    Chevy   Corvette
1999    Chevy   Cruz
2001    Ford    Mustang
2001    Ford    Shelby
2001    Ford    SHO
```

My main issue seems to come from the CSV.foreach method which turns each csv row of data into a separate array.  If I try to split the array I cannot seem to get it to create a new row as it reads the csv data line by line.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need a CSV reader and writer. Do you have both of those? If so, it's a case of writing multiple lines for each input line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about that ?

```
require 'csv'

desired_array = []

CSV.foreach('myfile.csv', :headers => true) do |csv_obj|
  csv_obj["Model"].split(/;\s*/).each do |model|
    new_row = [csv_obj["Year"], csv_obj["Make"], model]
    desired_array.push(new_row)
  end
end

p desired_array
```

Which gives the following array :

```
[
  ["1999", "Chevy", "Camaro"], 
  ["1999", "Chevy", "Corvette"], 
  ["1999", "Chevy", "Cruz"], 
  ["2001", "Ford", "Mustang"], 
  ["2001", "Ford", "Shelby"], 
  ["2001", "Ford", "SHO"]
]
```

Comment: `split("; ")` or `split(/;\s*/)` would probably be better.

Comment: @Jordan You're right! I think your second option is cleverer (to match multiple spaces) so I'll take that one.

Comment: @ Jordan, that is perfect.  Thank you so much!